# Card results or list results for mobile web app

Tags: interface, search-results, user-expectation, human-interface-guideline

I want to know which approach to show results is the better one.

The web-app shows roughly 10-20 results, and I want to know if it is better when the user sees these results in a normal list-view (table-view), or as a full-width card which the user can swipe to the left and right?

The application shows a map on the top half of the screen, and the bottom half of the screen is for the text-results.

[Here](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?3veRf9N_) (the first demo on that site) is an example of the full-width div which I mean.

I made a mockup in order to visualize my question:

[image: Result list vs. Result card]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## List view

List view with sections provides better performance (sub-linear), as it allows more quick filtering (via provided information architecture) of the search results. Also observing results in a list, user use "information scent" abilities to analyse the results and possibly correct search request. 
Advantages of the list view are:

- providing structured hierarchical results
- using IA for filtering results
- sub-linear performance time (as non-relevant sections are dropped)
  [image]

Scientific background for this choice and image source is: [How to design interfaces for choice: Hick-Hyman law and classification for information architecture](https://www.academia.edu/6549784/How_to_design_interfaces_for_choice_Hick-Hyman_law_and_classification_for_information_architecture).

## Cards view

Cards provides linear-search time with the worst result of 19 swipping. This is too long and boring way for a user. Using usability terms, this way increases time of the task execution (low performance) and leads to low satisfaction.

Disadvantages are:

- linear search time
- exhaustive swipping interaction
- non-structured presentation of the information which leads to mental load
- possible dropping of search interaction (physical and mental overload)

To fix the issues with card view you could order the cards by relevance, this allows to increase usability metrics, but could be hard to implement.